# SSRS - Using Parameters as part of a Dataset/Report Query

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to run an SSRS report using the following Dataset Query:

```
SELECT        timesheet_entry.ASSIGNMENT_ID, timesheet_entry.ENTRY_DATE, timesheet_entry.UPDATE_DATE, timesheet_entry.HOURS, timesheet_entry.COMMENT, 
                     project.PROJECT_ID, project.NAME AS Name_Of_Project, project.DESCRIPTION, project.PROJECT_MANAGER, user_to_department.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
                     user_to_department.USER_ID, users.USER_ID AS User_ID2, users.USERNAME, users.FIRST_NAME, users.LAST_NAME, 
                     users.DEPARTMENT_ID AS DEPARTMENT_ID2, users.ACTIVE AS ACTIVE2, user_department.NAME, CONCAT(Users.LAST_NAME, ", ", Users.FIRST_NAME) 
                     AS Full_Name, Customer.NAME AS Project_Cat
FROM            user_department, user_to_department, project,    Project_Assignment, Timesheet_entry, Users, Customer
WHERE (timesheet_entry.ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN (?) and (?)) AND (User_Department.NAME IN ('" & Join(Parameters!Parameter3.Value, "', '") & "'))     AND
(user_department.DEPARTMENT_ID = user_to_department.DEPARTMENT_ID) AND (project.PROJECT_ID = project_assignment.PROJECT_ID) AND 
                     (project_assignment.ASSIGNMENT_ID =  timesheet_entry.ASSIGNMENT_ID) AND (project_assignment.USER_ID = users.USER_ID)  AND 
                     (users.USER_ID = user_to_department.USER_ID) AND (Project.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID)
```

When I try to run the report, I receive all column headings, but no data.  I know that the problem is my third '?', which is part of a text parameter that can have multiple values.  When I make the query with that ? as a singular value, I get data back.  Hoping someone can point out whether my syntax is wrong.

Also, I need to have this done within the query itself, utilizing it as a Filter in the dataset causes the report to run longer than desired.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What DBMS are you using for your data? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

Comment: @R.Richards - MySQL Can be used in SSRS?

Comment: You can, it's just a different way of doing it. You have to use an expression for the query. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05536c48-9342-4b0e-97df-9134e9eaf2f6/passing-multivalue-parameter-using-mysql-in-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you for the responses!  The report is sitting on top of a MySQL server.